# Click button using class in Python selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I tried using both xpath and classname to locate and click the button. However, nothing is working.

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='sc-cqCuEk ffSPoi MuiButtonBase-root sc-dliRfk hLpdQI MuiAccordionSummary-root Mui-expanded MuiAccordionSummary-gutters sc-kAKrxA ALFEK']").click()

button class="sc-cqCuEk ffSPoi MuiButtonBase-root sc-iqzUVk gChJxn MuiIconButton-root
MuiIconButton-sizeLarge sc-dhVevo eheiFN" tabindex="0" type="button">svg class="sc-eMigcr
kvMRMj MuiSvgIcon-root MuiSvgIcon-fontSizeMedium sc-BOulX fmYgpR" focusable="false" aria-
hidden="true" viewBox="0 0 24 24" data-testid="KeyboardArrowUpIcon">path d="M7.41 15.41 12
10.83l4.59 4.58L18 14l-6-6-6 6z">

svg class="sc-eMigcr kvMRMj MuiSvgIcon-root MuiSvgIcon-fontSizeMedium sc-BOulX fmYgpR"
focusable="false" aria-hidden="true" viewBox="0 0 24 24" data-
testid="KeyboardArrowUpIcon">
/path>

Comment: Post your code, what have you tried until now? Post the url as well.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @platipus_on_fire_333 Please check now

Comment: What is the url you are accessing?

Comment: @platipus_on_fire_333 It is a company url that requires login

Answer (score 0):

Try locating and clicking it with

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "sc-cqCuEk.ffSPoi.MuiButtonBase-root.sc-iqzUVk.gChJxn.MuiIconButton-root.MuiIconButton-sizeLarge.sc-dhVevo.eheiFN"))).click()
```

You will also need the following imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time as t
```

EDIT: In the unlikely scenario in which you have absolutely identical X number of buttons and you want to click all of them (?!?!), you can do something like this:

```
buttons = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "sc-cqCuEk.ffSPoi.MuiButtonBase-root.sc-iqzUVk.gChJxn.MuiIconButton-root.MuiIconButton-sizeLarge.sc-dhVevo.eheiFN")))
for button in buttons:
    button.click()
    t.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: so all the buttons on this page have the same class name. how can i click all of them?

Comment: You find a differential between them. If they are absolutely identical, you use something like `buttons = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "..  whatever that is--")))` and iterate through them, and click each of them.

Comment: Can you please provide a sample code to iterate all of them?